# Delete Oracle - Web Api

Tags: banco-de-dados, oracle, spring-boot, spring-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Estou tentando fazer este Codigo do springboot, virar um codigo em WebApi

```
@RequestMapping("/deletarEvento")
    public String deletarEvento(long codigo)
{
        Evento evento = er.findByCodigo(codigo);
        er.delete(evento);
        return "redirect:/eventos";
}
```

Mais quando eu tento fazer

```
@RequestMapping(value="/deletarEvento", method=RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public String deletarEvento(long codigo)
{
        Evento evento = er.findByCodigo(codigo);
        er.delete(evento);
        return "redirect:/eventos";
}
```

ele da este erro :
There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
Failed to convert value of type `'java.lang.String' to required type 'long';` nested exception is `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "deletarEvento"`

---

Classe Evento

package com.vestibulartio.models;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="evento")
public class Evento{

```
@Id
@Column(name="codigo")
private Long codigo;


//@OneToMany
//private List<Convidado> convidado;

@Column(name="nome")
private String nome;
@Column(name="local")
private String local;
@Column(name="data")
private String data;
@Column(name="horario")
private String horario;

public Long getCodigo() {
    return codigo;
}
public void setCodigo(Long codigo) {
    this.codigo = codigo;
}
public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}
public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}
public String getLocal() {
    return local;
}
public void setLocal(String local) {
    this.local = local;
}
public String getData() {
    return data;
}
public void setData(String data) {
    this.data = data;
}
public String getHorario() {
    return horario;
}
public void setHorario(String horario) {
    this.horario = horario;
}
```

}
package com.vestibulartio.models;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="evento")
public class Evento{

```
@Id
@Column(name="codigo")
private Long codigo;


//@OneToMany
//private List<Convidado> convidado;

@Column(name="nome")
private String nome;
@Column(name="local")
private String local;
@Column(name="data")
private String data;
@Column(name="horario")
private String horario;

public Long getCodigo() {
    return codigo;
}
public void setCodigo(Long codigo) {
    this.codigo = codigo;
}
public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}
public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}
public String getLocal() {
    return local;
}
public void setLocal(String local) {
    this.local = local;
}
public String getData() {
    return data;
}
public void setData(String data) {
    this.data = data;
}
public String getHorario() {
    return horario;
}
public void setHorario(String horario) {
    this.horario = horario;
}
```

}

Comment: Pode postar a classe `Evento`?

Comment: @StatelessDev colocado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu método de deletar tem a seguinte a assinatura:

```
public String deletarEvento(long codigo)
```

Ele espera um `codigo`, que é o `id` que você passa para o método `findById()`. Logo, na URL que faz a chamada para o método de deletar, você deve passar um código, porém, veja como está montada sua URL:

```
@RequestMapping("/deletarEvento")
```

Cadê o `codigo`? Para o Spring, o código é tudo o que vem depois da barra, no caso, `"deletarEvento"`, que é uma String e que, obviamente, não consegue ser convertida para `long`, que é o que o método de deletar espera. Essa é a explicação da mensagem de erro que você tomou:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "deletarEvento"
```

A URL correta que seu método espera é algo mais ou menos assim, com um número que represente o código do Evento que você quer apagar:

```
http://blablabla/deletarEvento/1
```

Para a gente chegar nisso, experimente alterar seu método para isto aqui:

```
@RequestMapping("/deletarEvento/{id}", method=RequestMethod.DELETE)
public String deletarEvento(@PathVariable("id") long codigo) {
   Evento evento = er.findByCodigo(codigo);
   er.delete(evento);
   return "redirect:/eventos";
}
```

Dessa forma, estamos dizendo ao Spring para que ele alimente a variável `codigo` apenas com o vier dentro de `{id}`. Agora, ele saberá como lidar com aquela URL que esperamos.

Apenas cuidado com uma coisa. Da maneira como você fez sua lógica, o método `delete()` espera um `Evento`, mas, e se o `findById()` não encontrar um `Evento`? Sim, você vai tomar um `NullPointerException` quando tentar apagar. Pense a respeito e trabalhe sua lógica para prever casos em que um evento não seja encontrado no banco de dados ;)

Por fim, dê uma procurada sobre Spring Data, especialmente como fazer com que o Spring crie sozinho pra você os métodos CRUD. Comece por [aqui](http://blog.algaworks.com/spring-data-jpa/).

Se essa resposta lhe ajudou, marque-a como correta para outros a usarem também.